# Does Clojure's memoize force the evaluation of its arguments?

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, memoization

In Clojure if I memoize a function, name it `f` and call it on an argument `a`.

If `a` is a large lazy value, does memoize return a value based on matching the thunk as opposed to forcing the evaluation of `a` and matching on the result?

Where a thunk is the unevaluated part of the lazy sequence.

If this isn't the case is there a built-in way to get this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated by mikera, `memoize` doesn't handle infinite lazy seqs. I'm adding this answer to provide a short description of the implementation reasons for this (plus two ideas for identity-based memoization schemes, one simple, one more complex). *(Edit: actually there is a simple general identity-based solution, see below.)*

#### Why it doesn't work

`memoize` uses a hash map to store the mapping from arguments to values and hash maps use `clojure.lang.Util/hasheq` when determining if an object is one of their keys (except empty maps which just return `false`). Since `hasheq`'s implementation for lazy seqs forces the entirety of the seq, asking any map if an infinite lazy seq is one of its keys will cause it to go into an infinite, memory-exhausting loop. Thus the same goes for `memoize`.

Strictly speaking, initially the map is an array map. (In Clojure, for reasons of efficiency, small maps are usually array maps; if enough items are `assoc`'d onto an array map, the return value becomes a hash map.) However non-empty array maps *also* fail to handle infinite lazy seqs due to a similar reason involving an equivalence-checking method.

#### A solution

`System/identityHashCode` returns whatever `hashCode` would return for a given objects if it used the default implementation (whether or not its `hashCode` is overridden).

```
(defprotocol PWrapped
  (-unwrap [this]))
PWrapped

(defn wrap [o]
  (reify
    Object
    (hashCode [_] (System/identityHashCode o))
    PWrapped
    (-unwrap [_] o)))

;;; adapted from clojure.core/memoize, (C) Rich Hickey, EPL-licenced
(defn memoize
  "Returns a memoized version of a referentially transparent function. The
  memoized version of the function keeps a cache of the mapping from arguments
  to results and, when calls with the same arguments are repeated often, has
  higher performance at the expense of higher memory use."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [f]
  (let [mem (atom {})]
    (fn [& args]
      (if-let [e (find @mem (map wrap args))]
        (val e)
        (let [ret (apply f args)]
          (swap! mem assoc (map wrap args) ret)
          ret)))))
```

Now you can do this (which wouldn't work with the regular `memoize`):

```
user> (def r (lazy-cat (range 10000) (prn :foo) (range)))
#'user/r
user> (def f (memoize #(apply + (take 100 %))))
#'user/f
user> (f [1 2 3])
6
user> (f r)
4950
```

---

*Original discussion of alternative implementations follows.*

I don't think there is a built-in solution using pointer equality. To implement one as general as `memoize`, you'd have to implement a map structure using pointer-equality-based hashing (viz. `System/identityHashCode`). Or you could build a simple "most recently used" cache with `clojure.lang.PersistentQueue`.

Comment: so I will have to create an alternate version of memoize if I don't want to force the evaluation of even a finite lazy seq? Based perhaps on `identical?`?

Comment: Yes. If you want to base it on `identical?`, you might want to base it on `clojure.lang.PersistentQueue` -- put new args onto the queue in `[arg value]` packages, use something like `(some #(if (identical? (nth % 0) new-arg) %) queue)` to find previously computed values (returning `%` -- the vector -- for later unpacking so that `false` and `nil` are handled well) and evict items once the queue grows beyond a certain size (`PersistentQueue` can be `pop`'d at the opposite end to that on which it accepts `conj`s).

Comment: Happy to help! Actually there might be a simpler solution -- wrap objects with `(defn wrap (fn [o] (reify Object (hashCode [this] (System/identityHashCode o)) PWrapped (-unwrap [_] o)))` (with `PWrapped` an appropriately defined protocol), then put them in a regular map. Let me test this, I'll edit it into the answer if it works.

Comment: For what it's worth, Java already has an IdentityHashMap in java.util. You could use this as the backing store for your memoization cache, except for the many obvious problems that would arise :P.

Answer (score 5):

Memoize will memoize on the basis of the *value* of whatever argument you pass to it.

Therefore **memoize works fine with lazy sequences as arguments**: because it looks at the value of the sequence it will force evaluation *if needed*.

This does however mean that you **can't use infinite lazy sequences**, since the use of memoize can force evaluation of them which will clearly not end well.....

Comment: +1 for the reasoning behind the design. You might want to use the bold face for the "you can't use infinite lazy sequences" part to avoid raising false hopes, though. ;-)